# Cummulative addition on a vector of maps in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a data set that looks like this

```
[{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}]
```

I want to transform it into a cummulative map that looks like

```
{1 "a" 3 "b" 6 "c"}
```

I think my current approach is long winded. So far I have come up with

```
(reduce 
  (fn [sum item] 
      (assoc sum (+ (reduce + (keys sum)) 
                    (key (first item))) 
                 (val (first item)))) 
   split-map)
```

but the addition on the keys is incorrect. Does anyone know how I can improve on this?

Comment: If your input data has any 0s in it your problem is sorta unsolvable. Are you sure you want the output to be a map rather than a seq of pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation of the computation and it makes extensive use of Clojure sequence functions:

```
(defn cumul-pairs [data]
  (zipmap (rest (reductions ((map (comp key first)) +) 0 data))
          (map (comp val first) data)))

(cumul-pairs [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}])
;; => {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}
```

In this code, the expression `(rest (reductions ((map (comp first keys)) +) 0 data))` computes the keys of the resulting map and the expression `(map (comp first vals) data)` computes the values. Then we combine them with [zipmap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/zipmap). The function [reductions](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions) works just like [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) but returns a sequence of all intermediate results instead of just the last one. The curious looking subexpression `((map (comp first keys)) +)` is the reducing function, where we use a [map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map)ping transducer to construct a reducing function from the [+](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/+) reducing function that will map the input value before adding it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was very helpful. I'm selecting this as the accepted answer since it's a succint one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

and one more fun version:

```
(->> data
     (reductions (fn [[sum] m] (update (first m) 0 + sum)) [0])
     rest
     (into {}))

;;=> {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}
```

the trick is that reduction function operates on previous and current key-value pairs updating the current pair's key:

```
(reductions (fn [[sum] m] (update (first m) 0 + sum)) [0] data)
;;=> ([0] [1 "a"] [3 "b"] [6 "c"])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you fancy transducers:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.xforms :as xf])
(let [data [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}]]
    (into {} (comp
                 (map first)
                 (xf/multiplex [(map last)
                                (comp (map first) (xf/reductions +) (drop 1))])
                 (partition-all 2)) data))
=> {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an awkward problem to solve succintly.  Here is one way:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let-spy
    [x1       [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}]
     nums     (mapv #(first (first %)) x1)
     chars    (mapv #(second (first %)) x1)
     nums-cum (reductions + nums)
     pairs    (mapv vector nums-cum chars)  ; these 2 lines are
     result   (into {} pairs)]              ;   like `zipmap`
    (is= result {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"})))
```

By using my [favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template)
we are able to use `let-spy` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo)
and see the results printed at each step:

```
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
x1       => [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}]
nums     => [1 2 3]
chars    => ["a" "b" "c"]
nums-cum => (1 3 6)
pairs    => [[1 "a"] [3 "b"] [6 "c"]]
result   => {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

When it is working with all unit tests, just trim off the `-spy` part to leave a normal `(let ...)`form.

---

Be sure to see this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet.

Comment: Thank you. The process here was easy to reason about. I also hadn't heard of Tupelo previously, very useful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest (most readable) version:

```
(def ml [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}])
(defn cumsum [l] (reductions + l))

(let [m  (into (sorted-map) ml)]
  (zipmap  (cumsum (keys m)) (vals m)))

;; => {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}
```

Comment: @AlanThompson Thank you! I improved `(into {} ml)` to `(into (sorted-map) ml)`.

Comment: it is still flawed: `[{2 "b"} {1 "a"} {3 "c"}]` -> `{1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}` while it should be `{2 "b", 3 "a", 6 "c"}` .. you see: when the maps are not sorted by key in input it leads to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
(defn f [v]
      (zipmap (reductions + (mapcat keys v)) (mapcat vals v)))
```

which works with the original vector of maps:

```
(f [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c"}])

;; => {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c"}
```

.. and also with maps of varying length:

```
(f [{1 "a"} {2 "b"} {3 "c" 4 "d"} {5 "e" 6 "f" 7 "g"}])

;; => {1 "a", 3 "b", 6 "c", 10 "d", 15 "e", 21 "f", 28 "g"}
```